# CSS not centering when changing width

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight.js

I have the following code. It simply makes the python script formatted, with the colors using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).

```js
hljs.highlightAll();

 function clicked(){
      if(document.getElementById("code").style.display === "block"){
          document.getElementById("code").style.display = "none" 

      }else{
          document.getElementById("code").style.display = "block" 
      }
  }
```

```css
html{
    text-align: center;
}

#code{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px; /* removing this line will center */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.7.2/build/styles/atom-one-dark.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.7.2/build/highlight.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="clicked()">Show Code</button>
    <pre id="code"><code>print('hello world')</code></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

After clicking the button, it will not center the code. But if you uncomment the line which changes the width in the CSS file, it centers. Why does it not center when I change the width?

Comment: because the text will only cenetr within the given box. If you declare a fixed width instead of default auto. then the wrapping element of the etxt will have a fixed width starting from the left instead of spanning the entire width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align` is not the best thing to reach for when centering content. You'd be better off using `flex` layout on the container (e.g. `body`).

```js
hljs.highlightAll();

 function clicked(){
      if(document.getElementById("code").style.display === "block"){
          document.getElementById("code").style.display = "none" 

      }else{
          document.getElementById("code").style.display = "block" 
      }
  }
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#code{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px; /* removing this line will center */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.7.2/build/styles/atom-one-dark.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.7.2/build/highlight.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="clicked()">Show Code</button>
    <pre id="code"><code>print('hello world')</code></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `margin: 0 auto;` to center the div like

```
#code{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```js
hljs.highlightAll();

 function clicked(){
      if(document.getElementById("code").style.display === "block"){
          document.getElementById("code").style.display = "none" 

      }else{
          document.getElementById("code").style.display = "block" 
      }
  }
```

```css
html{
    text-align: center;
}

#code{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.7.2/build/styles/atom-one-dark.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.7.2/build/highlight.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="clicked()">Show Code</button>
    <pre id="code"><code>print('hello world')</code></pre>
</body>
</html>
```